# Nest.js / Server Side rendering with React and assests

Tags: reactjs, nestjs, server-side-rendering

There will be no code cause I'm a little bit misunderstood the core principle of server rendering I guess.

I have:

Nest.js with configured Handlebars. It's built with TypeScript out of the box. I don't use webpack here.
I also created a standalone folder with a client part of my application. There are React, webpack etc configured and working.

I need to create a server rendering. For this purpose, I use ReactDOMServer. Everything works unless it bumps into SVG components and CSS modules.

And here goes my question - how to deal with it?
What's the proper way? Should I replicate webpack config on my server side (I mean for assets), or is there a way to make it works with TypeScript (npm run build)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: are you trying to serve the assets files?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to recreate exactly the same structure as it would be with my client webpack.

Comment: you have to serve static files

Answer (score 1):

You have to serve the assets files https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static

you have to install @nestjs/serve-static

```
imports: [
  ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
    rootPath: join(__dirname, 'directory') // path to your files,
  }),
],
```

Comment: But what if we have two dev servers? How do we point to another webpackdev server?